# Как запросом к Django ORM вытянуть основную модель вместе со связанными моделями?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Друзья. Есть затуп в использовании Django ORM.
Как выполнить запрос, который вытащит всю инфу о модели "Car", а также поля из связанных по ForeignKey моделей?
Итоговый состав полей должен быть таким: `name, runame, timecode, color, engine, body`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    """Главная модель"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Системное название", unique=True)
    runame = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Русское название", unique=True)
    timecode = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class CarColor(models.Model):
    """Related модель для Car"""
    color = models.IntegerField()
    car_key = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='car_color')

class CarEngine(models.Model):
    """Related модель для Car"""
    engine = models.IntegerField()
    car_key = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='car_engine')

class CarBody(models.Model):
    """Related модель для Car"""
    body = models.IntegerField()
    car_key = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='car_body')
```

По идее, должно как-то работать через `select_related` или `prefetch_related`, но ничего толкового не выходит.
Help, please, SOS

Comment: Что именно значит "ничего толкового не выходит"?

Comment: Берете `car` и понеслась: `car.name`, `car.runame`, `car.timecode`, `car.car_color.color`, `car.car_engine.engine` и `car.car_body.body`. Я бы только в этом случае поля у связанных моделей поправил, чтобы было, например, `car.color.name`.

Comment: Какая-то странная модель данных. Т.е. конкретный цвет может иметь только одна машина, но одна машина может иметь целый набор цветов, то же самое про двигатель и корпус. Вы уверены? Или я что-то путаю? И действительно, все должно работать через prefetch_related, что именно у вас вышло, со стектрейсами, описанием фактического поведения и желаемого поведения, посните?

Comment: Начните с проверки моделей ваших. Со 150% уверенностью утрвеждал бы, что foreigh key поля должны быть у модели `Car`. Поэтому "ничего толкового и не выходит".

Comment: Про автомобили это я от балды модель придумал, в ней нет смысла, мне сам механизм доступа к связанным полям важен. Я уже на пути к решению. На данный момент открыл для себя, что можно получить связанные поля при помощи `Model.objects.values('field1', 'field2', 'rel1__relfield1', 'rel2__relfield2')`, где field1, field2 - родные поля модели; rel1, rel2 - related _name полей с ForeignKey; relfield1, relfield2 - любые другие поля кроме ForeignKey из связанных моделей.